# How can I get a long lived accestoken with facebook php SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, token

Hi I am using the JSDK to login with FB.login and then using the PHP SDK to get user information. Now I need to get a extended accestoken but this simply don't work:

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

this throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::setExtendedAccessToken() in....
```

right now my accesstoken just works for a few minutes and this causes problems any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Update your SDK, https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk. You are looking  for this line https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L351

Comment: Thanks man, dind't know it had come out a new version of the SDK since I downloaded mine.

Comment: Just noticed that this is not really working for me, I have the new SDK and using the function setExtendedAccessToken() and my token is lasting longer but only for like 30 minutes(before it was like 1 or 2 minutes) then it expires. as I understood it would last alot longer then that, any ideas?

Comment: @user1593846 No idea, that will depend on your code. I don't see your code so I wouldn't know what's "not really working". Your initial problem was that you could not find the function.

Comment: Okey so to explain the code fast I am getting my facebook friends and comparing the ids of those friends with my database to see if they are registerd on my site. So I am doing it like this: http://pastebin.com/Uhc4sZTG